# Extract data from local server database to client computers (via windows application)

Tags: windows, lan

At work, we have local area network which consists of 1 server and 11 client computers.
I am planning on building an application which runs on client computers that extracts data from the database on server and use the data on calculations and show the result.
The database belongs to an accounting application and the application I will make will run parallel to this application.

Since we have firewall installed, all ports are closed.
So what are my options here and what would you do if you were in my position?

Comment: Can the clients communicate with the server in any way? If not, do they (both the clients and the server) have internet access?

Comment: @FiddlingAway Both server and clients have internet access and share same network connection. We use shared folders on server.

Comment: What kind of a DBMS does the accounting software use? Is it PosgreSQL, MS Access, MariaDB running on Xampp / Wamp, or is it Sybase / SQL Anywhere, or something else entirely? The reason I'm asking - depending on the DBMS, perhaps creating an API of some kind would work for you. Your client applications would be contacting the API, and not the DB directly.

Comment: @FiddlingAway The database accounting software uses is SQL Server. And I also thought about creating an API but thought there might be an easier way to achieve what I want. That's why I asked here because LAN & Network is not my expertise.